# Sentence segmentation tools to use when input sentence has no punctuation (is normalized)

Tags: nlp, text-segmentation

Suppose there is a sentence like "find me some jazz music and play it", where all the text is normalized and there are no punctuation marks (output of a speech recognition library).

What online/offline tools can be used to do "sentence segmentation" other than the naive approach of splitting on conjunctions ?

Input:

> find me some jazz music and play it

Output:

> find me some jazz music
>   play it

Comment: Can you provide more input/output examples to help us understand why simple conjunction splitting is not good enough for this problem?

Comment: If you do a simple conjunction split, you would have lost shared objects/attributes across the two sentences. In the example stated above, "play it" has already lost "music attributes". I would like to segment the sentence semantically not syntactically, sorry for not making this clear !

Comment: So you want to do 'coreference resolution' (google it), and after that split on conjunctions?
By doing that your output would be something like ['find me some jazz music', 'play the jazz music']

Answer (score 1):

A [dependence parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a semantic role tagger like mate tools etc... for this. It will extract the predicates and the related arguments in prop bank style.